# Powershell save directory path from ls search?

Tags: windows, powershell, dynamic, ls

I am trying to recursively search a directory for a specified file that contains an .exe and then save that directory path to then use in a variable later.

I figured that using:

```
ls -recurse -filter "PsExec.exe" | sort name | ft directory,name
```

will display the directory that contains the .exe. Is there a way that I can save off the directory so that I can later use it to reference the .exe in another part of my script?
The .exe will be saved in a folder dynamically named so that's why I can't hardcode it's path.

Comment: Is that file guaranteed to be unique? Or will it return a set of files?

Comment: Can you pass the result in the array `$items =ls -recurse -filter "PsExec.exe" | sort name | ft directory,name`

Comment: You don't want to pass the results of `format-table` into `$items`, but the rest is a good idea.

Comment: yes, the file is guaranteed to be unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to save the full path to a single instance of the file, you can use

```
$path = ls -recurse -filter "PsExec.exe" | select -first 1 | select -expand FullName
```

Or you can save multiple properties if you want

```
$file = ls -recurse -filter "PsExec.exe" | select -first 1 | select Name,FullName,Directory

$file.Name
$file.FullName
$file.Directory
```

Comment: Is there a way for it to search hidden folders too?

Comment: Add `-Force` flag to the `ls` call